# Searching RichTextBox and deleting all between

Tags: richtextbox, parentheses

I'm having a little trouble trying to figure out how to search all the text in my RichTextBox and delete everything between the parentheses (including the parentheses). I have a lot of files with different comments wrote in the parentheses that may have different text in them.

Example : This is my text in the text box (AS YOU CAN SEE HERE). I am wanting to be able to read the entire text box (This would be another comment) and delete the out.

Result: This is my text in the text box. I am wanting to be able to read the entire text box and delete the out.

The rich text box are usually longer files than just a couple lines. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("\(.+?\)");
```

If you are using a richtextbox or a textbox:

```
rtb.Text = r.Replace(rtb.Text,"");
```

You can do this without reading the file into the richttextbox:

```
string filetext = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
filetext = r.Replace(filetext,"");
File.WriteAllText("file.txt",filetext);
```

Or in one line:

```
File.WriteAllText("file.txt",r.Replace(File.ReadAllText("file.txt"),""));
```

You can loop all files in a directory:

```
foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)
    File.WriteAllText(file,r.Replace(File.ReadAllText(file),""));
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still new to this so this helps alot. I ended up changing it to Regex r = new Regex("\\\(.+?\\\)"); and it worked great.